# How to sleep in WindowsPhone after changing control color

Tags: windows-phone

I have button which navigate to next PortraitPage.xaml. I would like to change color of this button after Tap and then after 1s navigate to next page, so the User could see change. If I use code like this:

```
button.Background = RED;
Sleep(1000);
NavigateToNextPage();
```

the Background property of the button doesn't change.

Comment: You need to post more code in order to understand what is missing

Comment: Thats all code. I have simple button, which simple navigate to the next page. But before it happens I would like to change color of this button, wait 1s and than navigate.

Comment: Ok. Then you should perform your Sleep() in a background thread, or else you won't see the GUI update before Sleep() kicks in, then navigate to next page. Try to replace Sleep(1000) with "await Task.Delay(1000);" At least the GUI does not lock...